# In javascript stringify array does not return expected behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm getting a weird behavior out of javascript, anyone can help me?

When I click on the 'test' link I get an alert with this string: "[]"

I was expecting something like : "[{'temp':25},{'thermState':'Notte'}]"

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function test(){
        this.radioStates="";
        this.state = [];
        this.state["temp"]=25;
        this.state["thermState"]="Notte";
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.state));
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="test()">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have associative arrays in Javascript. `this.state["temp"]=25` should be `this.state{ "temp" : 25 }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change to :

```
this.state = {}; ................
```

properties can be added to object not to arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.state = {}; // Declare as object
this.state["temp"]=25;
this.state["thermState"]="Notte";
alert(JSON.stringify(this.state));
```

or

```
this.state = [];
this.state[this.state.length]= {temp: 25};
this.state[this.state.length]= { thermState: "Notte"};
alert(JSON.stringify(this.state));
```

The first works as an associative array / object, the second works as an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could get your expected output by saying:

```
this.state = [];
this.state[0] = { 'temp' : 25 };
this.state[1] = { 'thermState' : "Notte" };
```

[jsFiddle Demo producing your desired output](http://jsfiddle.net/MNduh/)

Let me try to explain the unexpected behaviour.

In Javascript, everything is an object. When you write `this.state = [];` your `this.state` variable becomes an Array object which is empty. You can add elements to it by writing `this.state[number] = x` or `this.state.push(x)`.

Javascript has no associative arrays. When you write `this.state["temp"]=25;` you are setting a property on your Array object. You are not putting anything to the array itself. Now `this.state` will have a property that you can access by `this.state.temp` or `this.state['temp']`, but it will not appear in the array itself, because it was not added to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `push`, **if you want state to be an array**:

```
this.state.push({"temp":25, "thermState": "Notte"});
```